# Publishing ZIPs to Artifactory from Jersey/JAX-RS Client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, artifactory

I have a set of requirements that require a Jersey/JAX-RS client to publish ZIP files to repos living on Artifactory. Specifically, I need to publish ZIPs to:

> http://artifactory01.example.org/artifactory/simple/libs-release-local/ourorg/somelib/1.0.0/

It looks like Artifactory exposes a [PUT endpoint](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact):

```
PUT /libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar {
    "uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar",
    "downloadUri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar",
    "repo": "libs-release-local",
    "path": "/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar",
    "created": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
    "createdBy": "userY",
    "size": "1024", //bytes
    "mimeType": "application/java-archive",
    "checksums": {
        "md5" : string,
        "sha1" : string
    },
    "originalChecksums": {
        "md5" : string,
        "sha1" : string
    }
}
```

Hence it looks like I need to PUT `somelib-1.0.0.zip` to the URL I identified above. My proposal to do this is as follows:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code for the PUT entity:
class Publication {
    @JsonProperty
    String uri

    @JsonProperty
    String downloadUri

    @JsonProperty
    String repo

    @JsonProperty
    String path

    @JsonProperty
    Date created

    @JsonProperty
    String createdBy

    @JsonProperty
    Integer size

    @JsonProperty
    String mimeType

    @JsonProperty
    Map<String,String> checksums

    @JsonProperty
    Map<String,String> originalChecksums
}
```

However, 2 problems:

#### Security

The security constraint on this endpoint requires a user with 'deploy' permissions. I have such a user, however I'm not sure how to implement this auth on the client-side. Does Artifactory use basic auth for its endpoints? If so, would something like this work (?):

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource(BASE_URI);
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("deployuser", "12345"));   // dummy credentials, obviously
```

#### PUT Entity

**Most importantly**, I'm not understanding what the `PUT` entity should be. Using Jersey/JAX-RS style POJOs, I might do something like:

```
// Again, Groovy pseudo-code
Publication publication = getSomehow()  // Ideally ZIP is read into portable format by this point

webResource.path("libs-release-local").path("ourorg").path("somelib").path("1.0.0").path("somelib-1.0.0.zip")
    .type(MediaType.???).entity(publication).put(???)
```

However, I still don't see how/where I send the actual ZIP file. There is the `path` field, which seems to specify the local (client-side) path to the binary, but that's just a string/reference, not the actual binary to publish!

Also, according to Wikipedia, ZIP media type is `application\zip`, but there is no such [`MediaType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) defined in JAX-RS.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Auth is good.
Re the entity, you don't need any. The JSON you see in the docs is the **result** of the PUT call.

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch (+1) - however, how is it possible that no PUT entity is needed on the request? How else do I publish the ZIP?!?

Comment: Or, @JBaruch, better yet, is the [Java Client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java) up to date and useable for this? If so, I'll try to avoid reinventing the wheel :-)

Comment: Thanks again @JBaruch (+1), last questions: (1) any docs on this client/example usage/etc.? And (2) What are the Maven coordinates for this? I see [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jfrog.artifactory.client%7Cartifactory-java-client-api%7C0.16%7Cjar) but its version (0.16) conflicts with what I see on Bintray (0.10)...ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Usage example is best shown in [the unit tests](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java/tree/master/services/src/test/java/org/jfrog/artifactory/client). And [that's the official package](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-tools/artifactory-client-java/view), latest version is 0.17.

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch (+1 again) so `jfrog.artifactory-tools:artifactory-java-client:0.17` for Maven/Gradle coords? Is this jcenter?